# Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a table called `productreview` with columns `productreviewid ,product id ,shopperid ,review,rating`

I have another table called `shopper` with columns `shopperid, shopid, logicalcode,fore name , surname ,postcode, dateof birth`

I want to create a stored procedure called `productreviewlist` with input parameters

```
@shopid int,
@forename nvarchar (10),
@surname nvarchar (10),
@postcode nvarchar (10),
@startdate datetime,
@enddate datetime
```

pls help me out for creating this stored procedure

Comment: In shopper table i dont  hav these columns startdate and end date

Comment: What exactly are you wanting the stored procedure to do?

Comment: it just displays the columns from shopper

Comment: Here is the documentation for `CREATE PROCEDURE`, you should be able to get started by looking at some of the examples on that page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Comment: This is not a question. If you try and do it yourself, and post what you've tried and tell us what didn't work, we can help you fix it. We're not going to do it for you; if we do, you won't learn to do it yourself.

Comment: pls help me out i hav an error in  creating this procedure at where statement  pls help me out

Comment: This is the fourth or fifth question in the past two hours asking people to do your work for you... You can't keep at this pace forever without people taking notice. Eventually you'll have to break down and learn how to work on your own.

Comment: You need to **get yourself a good book** on [T-SQL and stored procedure programming](http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-Stored-Procedure-Programming/dp/0072262281), read it, learn it, use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE productreview_list
(
    @shopid int,
    @forename nvarchar(10),
    @surname nvarchar (10),
    @postcode nvarchar(10),
    @startdate datetime,
    @enddate datetime
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT r.* FROM productreview r
INNER JOIN shopper s ON s.shopperid = r.shopperid
WHERE s.shopid = @shopid
AND s.forname = @forename
AND s.surname = @surname
AND s.postcode = @postcode
AND (s.dateofbirth <= @enddate AND s.dateofbirth >= @startdate)

END
```

You'll have to provide more info on what you actually need (text comparison, what you want to see with each review, if certain fields are optional, etc.).